# How to save apps data Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, save

I have been searching for many days on how to save my apps data. I found some stuff but it was very complicated and badly explained. I need that when I completely close my apps all the data I entered in the text field are still there when I open my apps again. I tried a tutorial but this only let me save about 8 textfields and I need to save thousands I am starting Objective-C and Xcode so if somebody want to give me an answer please make it very precise.

Comment: thousands of textfields? Are you serious? I would change the design of the app.

Answer (score 5):

Alright, what I'd suggest would be putting all the data from your text fields into an array and saving that to a file, then loading it when you re-open the app.

The first thing you need is a save file. This function will create one for you.

```
-(NSString*) saveFilePath{
NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                  @"myfilename.plist"];
return path;}
```

Now that that's done you need to create your saving array. Hopefully you have your thousands of textfields already fitted into an array of some sort. If not, this will be a painful process regardless of how you tackle it. But anyway... (Here, labelArray will be the array of all your text fields/labels/etc.)

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int i = 0;
while(i < labelArray.count){
   [myArray addObject: [labelArray objectAtIndex: i].text];
   i ++;
}
[myArray writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
[myArray release];
```

And the loading code would be something along the lines of

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self saveFilePath]]retain];
```

Then you'd simply load the data back into your array of text fields.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. Now i was wondering where do i put this code and if i put this code in my file is it gonna save all my textfield automatically or i need to tell him what textfield to save. I don't know what an array is or how to make one. I do have thousands of textfield but they are separated into 100 different .h and .m so please if someone can explain to me that would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: @proticsam If you've created thousands of textfields, hundreds of classes but you still don't know what an array is, you may have more fundamental issues than maintaining your app state. Have you tried any iPhone tutorials?

Comment: kubi's right, you should probably look at some iphone tutorials. Anyway, you'd need to put the save code inside a function for each .m file (and use a saveFilePath function with a slightly different filename so you don't overwrite your own stuff.) Then when that function gets called, your stuff for that class would be saved. The loading code would just go in your viewDidLoad file (for view controllers, you'll need a new function for custom classes).

Comment: Thank You for your help. For the last 3 weeks i have been watching and reading iphone tutorials and there is lots and lots of bad ones with outdated code so its very hard to learn stuff when everything change in each new version of xcode.

Comment: Hey guys. i just used this question to help get my program to save a few items, but do you have to save as an array? or can you simply save each NSString separately? Im having trouble reading the information on reopening the app.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your application architecture may be unsound if you are planning on saving thousands of text fields' data in the fraction of a second you get while your app is closing. It would probably be better to save these as the user enters the data instead of waiting to save all the data at once.

Answer (score 0):

To get the path you are going to write ( or read from! ) to, you do the following:

`NSString *writableDBPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.extension"];`

And then use a method like "writeToFile:automically:" of NSString or NSDictionary etc. to write to the path.